# why raw udp packet does not follow routing rules

Tags: c, routes, raw-sockets

I am trying to forge raw IP and UDP in C on a linux system (ArchLinux). For that, I used the following code

```
char *src_ip = "192.168.10.1";
char *dst_ip = "192.168.30.3";
short src_port = 22221;
short dst_port = 11111;

struct pseudo_header
{
    u_int32_t source_address;
    u_int32_t dest_address;
    u_int8_t placeholder;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t udp_length;
};

unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes)
{
   register long sum; 
   unsigned short oddbyte;
   register short answer;

   sum=0;
   while(nbytes>1) {
           sum+=*ptr++;
           nbytes-=2;
   }
   if(nbytes==1) {
           oddbyte=0;
           *((u_char*)&oddbyte)=*(u_char*)ptr;
           sum+=oddbyte;
   }

   sum = (sum>>16)+(sum & 0xffff);
   sum = sum + (sum>>16);
   answer=(short)~sum;

   return(answer);
}

void fill_ip(struct iphdr *iph, int lendata /*including udp header*/)
{  
   iph->ihl = 5;
   iph->version = 4;
   iph->tos = 0;
   iph->tot_len = sizeof (struct iphdr) + lendata;     //sizeof (struct udphdr) + strlen(data);
   iph->id = htonl (54321);        //Id of this packet
   iph->frag_off = 0;
   iph->ttl = 255; 
   iph->protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
   iph->check = 0;         //Set to 0 before     calculating checksum
   iph->saddr = inet_addr (src_ip);        //Spoof the source ip address
   iph->daddr = inet_addr (dst_ip);
   iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) iph, iph->tot_len);
}

void fill_udp(struct udphdr *udph, int lendata)
{
  udph->source = htons (src_port);
  udph->dest = htons (dst_port);
  udph->len = htons(8 + lendata);       //tcp header size

  /* CSUM */
  struct pseudo_header psh;
  psh.source_address = inet_addr(src_ip);
  psh.dest_address = inet_addr (dst_ip);
  psh.placeholder = 0;
  psh.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
  psh.udp_length = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + lendata );
  int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + lendata;
  char *pseudogram = malloc(psize);
  memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
  memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , udph , sizeof(struct udphdr) +     lendata);
  udph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) pseudogram , psize);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{


  char datagram[4096]={0};
  int s;

  s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
  assert(s != -1);

  //link to interface
  const char *opt;
  opt = "ens6";
  const int len = strnlen(opt, IFNAMSIZ);
  if (len == IFNAMSIZ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too long iface name");
    return 1;
  }
  assert(setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, opt, len) == 0);


  // IP header
  struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) datagram;

  //UDP header
  struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ip));

  // data
  char *data = datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);
  data[0] = 'a';

  fill_ip(iph,sizeof(struct udphdr) + 1/*len of data*/);
  fill_udp(udph,1);

  struct sockaddr_in sin;
  memset(&sin,0,sizeof(sin));
  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port = htons(dst_port);
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (dst_ip);

  sendto (s, datagram, iph->tot_len , 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin));

  return 0;
}
```

This code creates a UDP packet from 192.168.10.1 to 192.168.30.3 with source port 22221 and destination port 11111.

Then, I add a routing rule and delete the default route from the main table:

```
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.30.3 dport 11111 proto 17 table 2001
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.10.2 src 192.168.10.1 table 2001
sudo ip route del default
```

(The route for 192.168.10.2 is defined in the main table)

This eventually gives the following rules:

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from all to 192.168.30.3 dport 11111 lookup 2001 proto 17
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

And the following routes:

```
# ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.10.0 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 
local 192.168.10.1 dev ens6 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.10.1 
broadcast 192.168.10.255 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1
```

- 

```
# ip route show table 2001
default via 192.168.10.2 dev ens6 src 192.168.10.1 
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1
```

- 

```
# ip route show table main
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1
```

I expected to see my raw packet with wireshark on 192.168.10.2 and 192.168.30.3 but nothing. Do you know why? Maybe my raw socket does not follow the routing rule I defined? Note that the code works as expected if I don't touch the routing rules on my computer.

Comment: You're exactly correct.  Your mileage will vary from OS to OS (it sounds like you're on Linux) ... but  all bets are off in terms of expecting hand-crafted packets sent via "raw sockets" to obey all standard TCP/IP level behavior (like "route").  Look here: https://squidarth.com/networking/systems/rc/2018/05/28/using-raw-sockets.html

Comment: Indeed I am on Linux (I just edited my message to include this information).

Comment: As far as I understand, for the raw socket on Linux only the destination address is used for routing. Indeed `sudo ip rule add to 192.168.30.3 table 2001` works while `sudo ip rule add to 192.168.30.3 dport 11111 proto 17 table 2001` or `sudo ip rule add from 192.168.10.1 to 192.168.30.3 table 2001` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you need to `bind()` socket to interface IP address.

Raw sockets do follow routing rules, and your `setsockopt SO_BINDTODEVICE` is a right move, which will work in some cases such as with L3 (TUN) tunnels, however for a real Ethernet device you (also) need to `bind()` to its interface IP address.

The kernel does not inspect your IP header passed in `sendto buf`, but it inspects on which address/device the socket is bound to.